# query a mySQL database for the number of entries with a date later then the current date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have developed a project management system for tracking various items related to my daily work flow. I would like to query the database to show me the number of projects whose completion date has passed (If have missed a project deadline). Can some give me some direction on how to query the data base to compare the stored date with the current date and count the number of entries that meet this parameter?

Comment: What do your tables look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'count'
FROM my_table
WHERE my_datetime_column > NOW()
```

Although you probably want to find the dates in the *past* if you're looking for things that are overdue, so just flip that comparison operator around.

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

```
Select count(*) as myCount From myTable where CompletionDate > NOW();
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you are looking for (assuming that your deadline field is DATETIME type):

```
SELECT count(`id`) FROM `my_table` WHERE `deadline` < NOW();
```

If you want to play around with MYSQL datetime, you should read about it here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html